# Managing Windows7 important updates in multiple systems

Tags: windows-7, windows, debian, windows-update

I need to manage four Windows7 systems and occasionally I reinstall Windows in any one of them.

I only install Important Updates. I dont install Optional Updates.

What I do is download all msu files and install them with dism.

But what happens is the updates list gets changed every month with few old updates no longer needed and few new updates replacing them. That makes unwanted msu files in my collection and I have to cross check the list of 100+ with every fresh installation of windows, and delete the unwanted msu files manually.

So,

- How to manage this ever changing list of updates?
- Is there any path in Windows subdirectories that i can copy the msu/cab files to, and can just check for updates through windows update and install, so it uses those offline files? Just like debian based systems have under /var/cache/apt/archives/

I checked third party tools like WindowsUpdatesDownloader , but the lists in them are out-of-date by a month or two.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Server 2003 on up and the Windows 7 computers would be able to reach it, I would try and manage this issue with Windows Server Update Service (WSUS).  You would have direct control over the computers connected to it as far as what update goes to what computer.  Create a group and that group gets the updates assigned to the group and so on.  I would definitely research a WSUS solution in this case.